# How do I change the time zone for azure sql edge

Tags: sql-server, datetime, timezone, azure-sql-database

I have a serverless Azure SQL edge instance. I need to change the “server” time to be my time zone.
Looks like none of the traditional sql server stored procedures used for that exists on Edge.
Is there a way to change time zones on Edge?

Comment: You don't; stuff in Azure is always set to UTC. What are you *actually* trying to achieve here?

Comment: @ThomA trying to avoid the headache of modifying dates to my time zone. Display purposes and for when people put in a scheduled task with our time zone